# How to override the inline style by applying a new class in D3

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

All:

I used D3 to add style to SVG element like:

```
svg.append("rect")
   .attr("id", "testclass")
   .classed("hascolor", true)
   .style("fill", "red");
```

Then I define another class:

```
.nocolor{
    fill: transparent;
}
```

And when I want to apply this class to change style like:

```
svg.select("#testclass")
   .classed("nocolor", true);
```

The class of RECT changed, but the style did not apply( it only works when I use JS to change the style directly). I wonder if anyone could help with this to enable style changing by class on it?

Thanks

Comment: you can apply the class with svg.select('#testclass').attr('class', 'nocolor');

Comment: or use `!important` rule, which is not perfect, but overrides inline styles like so `.nocolor{fill: transparent !important;}`

Comment: @tomtomtom thanks, but add class way not work on my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline styles has priority over the css style.

(I know that maybe this exact portion of code is not going to work in your case but is just for demonstrative proposes). 
Here is a Jquery example, that you can test the style priority over inline style, first class that apply a rule and second class that apply a rule with !important.

HTML:

```
 <div id='theOne' style="color: green;" class="colorRed"> Something that needs to be colored </div>
```

CSS:

```
.colorRed {
    color: red;
}
.colorBlack {
    color: black!important;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#theOne').addClass('colorBlack');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nm0zma61/1/)

So posibles solutions to your problem are:

1) Add the rule fill: transparent as 'style' attribute.

2) Use a css class instead of the attribute style in the first step.

3) Add !important to the css Rule.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I can not use two classes is I need to decide the style dynamically in the first situation.

Comment: ok. So you need to override the attribute 'style' of the element or add !important to the css rule, (This only will work if the element hasn't important! in the style rule that it has applied). see sugestion number 3 and updated code for class .colorBlack

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that inline styles are more important than attributes from any selector, like from class you used, se even new class is applied, the inline style still exists thus is more important, however you can use !important rule which will override inline styling.

First things that came to mind:

```
.nocolor{
    fill: transparent !important;
}
```

or

```
svg.select("#testclass").style("fill", "transparent");
```